# How do I loop through a self referencial association for other associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have successfully set up a friendship self referencial association for `users` in my Ruby on Rails app after following  [Ryan Bates' railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association). I can successfully follow, unfollow, and view who is following. Now I want to pull in another element and I am not sure how to do it.

```
User has_many :workouts
```

I want to display the workouts for the users that I am following. Kind of like Twitter displays tweets for the users your are following. Can this be done given my below associations or do I need to set up another one, for instance,

```
Friendship has_many :workouts, :through => :users.
```

Here is the rest of the model information that you might need.

User.rb

```
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
  has_many :workouts, :dependent => :destroy
```

Friendship.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

Workout.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
```

If not additional associations needed, what is the syntax in the /users/show.html.erb view to display workouts for friends.

UPDATE:

It seems based on the answer from Josiah Kiehl below I am able to get this close. After testing in the console per his advice, I used the following code in the view:

```
<% current_user.friends[0].workouts.each do |workout| %>
  <%= workout.title %><br/>
<% end %>
```

But this seems to only return workouts for the first user that I followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

```
<% current_user.friends.each do |friend| %>
<h1><%= friend.name %></h1>
<% friend.workouts.each do |workout| %>
<p><%= workout.title %></p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Important to note is that for this to be db query effective, you probably want to create a scope or association that includes the workouts directly in the friends query. You could of course do it manually like this:

```
<% current_user.friends.all(:include => :workouts).each do |friend| %>
```

Edit:

If you want to associate the friends workout directly with the current_user, I think the easiest way is to create a manual method to associate the workouts.

```
def friends_workouts
  @friends_workouts ||= Workout.find_all_by_friend_id(self.friends.map(&:id), :order => "created_at DESC")
end
```

The problem with pure associations is that you would have multiple :through calls which is not supported afaik. This way it will at least not generate more than two db calls. First to load the friend ids and then to load all workouts associated with any of those.

Comment: I was hoping to integrate all the friends workouts into one stream. The first bit of code works for listing workouts by friends, and when I use the second I am getting an `undefined method for workout` error.

Comment: to be more specific the error is: `undefined method `workout' for #<User:0x1048d8e70>`

Comment: Also...I need to have the workouts displayed :order => "created_at DESC"

Comment: Okey, perhaps an associated :through relationship is what you're looking for. I'll edit my post with another example

Comment: I apologize for asking for more detail. I am self taught before about a year ago I had never programmed a thing. Can you tell me where this goes (controller/model/workouts/user) and what the syntax would be to call it? `@friends_workouts.each do |workout| %>`, etc.

Comment: It goes in the User model. That way you can call current_user.friends_workouts and loop through them in the views

Comment: Awesome...almost there. I got this error. `Couldn't find all Workouts with IDs (13,21,7) (found 1 results, but was looking for 3)`. I've never seen that before. Trying to workout through it with condition.

Comment: Looks like (from looking at the db) that the method you provided is calling the friend_id the workout_id. So for instance, the error says that it is looking for workouts with IDs 13,21,7 and when I look at the friendships table, those are the friend_id (the user_id of the friend).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should actually be Workout.find_all_by_friend_id

Comment: When I replace `Workout.find(self.friends.map(&:id), :order => "created_at DESC")` with `Workout.find_all_by_friend_id(self.friends.map(&:id), :order => "created_at DESC")` in the model I get an error: `undefined method `find_all_by_friend_id' for #<Class:0x105f4ae88>`

Comment: Okey, I just assumed that friend_id was the foreign_key in the Workout class. To clearify, rails implements a way to find by different attributes find_all_by_{attribute}. But since you probably use user_id, it should be find_all_by_user_id

Comment: No problem, just glad we got there in the end :)

Comment: I have another question related to this about how to restrict a view through a condition but don't know if I should break out as a new question or not. i.e. If the current_user is already following the user, don't display the follow button but a message `your are following this user`. Should I break out to a new question?

Comment: Yea, post a new question. Might be a bit off topic otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Are you having problems when doing something like this:

```
a = User.last
a.friends[0].workouts
```

Comment: I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'workouts' for nil:NilClass

Comment: actually when I did the above on user first it seemed to work...what would be the correct syntax in the view to call this?